# Rendering of React children in different DOM nodes

Tags: reactjs

Given that `React.Children` is a ["leaky abstraction"](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/61#issuecomment-431247764), ["is in maintenance mode"](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/61#issuecomment-584402735), and considered a [legacy API](https://react.dev/reference/react/Children), is there a preferred/recommended way to render a subset of `children` within a different DOM node?

Suppose I'm building a `Breadcrumbs` component that accepts an arbitrary number of `Item` children:

```
<Breadcrumbs>
  <Item>Item 1</Item>
  <Item>Item 2</Item>
  <Item>Item 3</Item>
  ...
</Breadcrumbs>
```

If the collective width of the items exceeds the container width, items are placed within an overflow menu. What would be the preferred way of rendering these overflown items within a different DOM node if not with `React.Children.toArray(children)`?

```
// Using `React.Children`
const Breadcrumbs = (props) => {
  const someCalculatedIndexSplit = 3;
  const items = React.Children.toArray(props.children);
  const overflownItems = items.splice(0, someCalculatedIndexSplit);
  const visibleItems = items.splice(someCalculatedIndexSplit);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        Overflown:
        {overflownItems.map(item => <div>{item}</div>)}
      </div>
      <div>
        Visible:
        {visibleItems.map(item => <div>{item}</div>)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

EDIT: I'm hoping to avoid `items={[{...}, {...}, ...]}` as well.

Comment: This sounds like [a job for refs](https://react.dev/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs) although I'd probably first try to not use an overflow menu and instead write CSS (especially taking advantage of `:has()` now that every browser supports it)

Comment: The breadcrumbs use case was just used as an example. I was hoping to understand rendering `children` within different DOM nodes more generally.

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't, your code should get generated such that CSS can do the rest as needed, so you'll need to sketch a real use-case =) (And note that you can of course always _change_ how things render by having state variables that get set based on what things look like post-render. Just because things don't fit immediately doesn't mean your code can't preallocate two sections of menu, render everything in the first, then go "ah that doesn't fit" and _rerender_ with items split over the two)